# How to return number keypad in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

My requirement when user enter in to a specific textfield numberpad will appear. When user clicked on done button number pad will dismiss can any one tell me the code.

Comment: how could this be a duplicate both questions are similar but different...... Prev one was just keyboard hiding and this question is with PhonePad. Sounds funny